# I am facing issues in TestNG only one annotation will work at a time

Tags: selenium, testng

If @Beforetest an @ Test @Aftertest present  then only beforetest will work if its not present then only test will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BeforeTest and @AfterTest are running before and after each @Test within the same class.
You can use @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod if you need them to run for tests from a child class.

Answer (score 0):

TestNg annotaions are some order to execute  please refer this https://www.simplilearn.com/know-about-testng-annotations-in-selenium-webdriver-article for more idea